# UnboundID LDAP SDK not following Referrals

Tags: java, grails, ldap, referrals, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I'm using the UnboundID LDAP Java SDK to connect a Groovy/Grails application to Active Directory.  Here are the connection options that I'm using:

```
  LDAPConnectionOptions options = new LDAPConnectionOptions()
  options.connectTimeoutMillis = 60000 // 1 minute
  options.followReferrals = true
  options.referralHopLimit = 10
  options.responseTimeoutMillis = 60000 // 1 minute
  options.useSynchronousMode = true
```

However, I still keep getting LDAPSearchExceptions with result code 10, which means that the server sent a referral.  Changing the referralHopLimit to a higher number doesn't help, so clearly the library isn't following the referrals.

So far I seem to only get this issue when using the LDAPConnection.getEntry method to load a specific entry specified by a DN.  I haven't yet received it when performing a search.  So I'm wondering if maybe the getEntry method isn't supposed to follow referrals and if that's the case, what's the best approach for manually following referrals or changing it's behavior?

Answer (score 2):

The getEntry method uses search behind the scenes, so if search works, then getEntry should also work.  I just ran a quick test and it works for me.  Using the latest LDAP SDK release (2.3.6) and the following code, I get the expected entry after following the referral.  If I comment out the "opts.setFollowReferrals(true)" line, then I get a referral exception:

```
import com.unboundid.ldap.listener.*;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.*;



public class ReferralTest
{
  public static void main(final String... args)
         throws Exception
  {
    final InMemoryDirectoryServerConfig cfg =
         new InMemoryDirectoryServerConfig("dc=example,dc=com");
    final InMemoryDirectoryServer ds1 = new InMemoryDirectoryServer(cfg);
    final InMemoryDirectoryServer ds2 = new InMemoryDirectoryServer(cfg);

    ds1.startListening();
    ds2.startListening();

    final LDAPConnectionOptions opts = new LDAPConnectionOptions();
    opts.setFollowReferrals(true);

    final LDAPConnection conn1 = ds1.getConnection(opts);
    final LDAPConnection conn2 = ds2.getConnection(opts);

    conn1.add(
         "dn: dc=example,dc=com",
         "objectClass: top",
         "objectClass: domain",
         "dc: example");
    conn1.add(
         "dn: ou=Referral Entry,dc=example,dc=com",
         "objectClass: top",
         "objectClass: organizationalUnit",
         "ou: Referral Entry",
         "description: This is a referral entry");

    conn2.add(
         "dn: dc=example,dc=com",
         "objectClass: top",
         "objectClass: domain",
         "dc: example");
    conn2.add(
         "dn: ou=Referral Entry,dc=example,dc=com",
         "objectClass: top",
         "objectClass: referral",
         "objectClass: extensibleObject",
         "ou: Referral Entry",
         "ref: ldap://127.0.0.1:" + ds1.getListenPort() +
              "/ou=Referral Entry,dc=example,dc=com");

    final Entry e = conn2.getEntry("ou=Referral Entry,dc=example,dc=com");
    System.out.println(e.toLDIFString());

    conn1.close();
    conn2.close();

    ds1.shutDown(true);
    ds2.shutDown(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm gonna try your example tomorrow and report back.  However, I have a feeling such a sterile example will work, even though similar code when connecting to our Active Directory instance is failing to follow referrals.  I also wanted to ask, do you think using a connection pool would change anything (I'm using a connection pool to connect to Active Directory)?

Comment: Whether or not a connection is part of a connection pool should not have any impact on the treatment of referrals.  And as long as a referral is properly formed, then it shouldn't matter what type of directory server sent it to the client.